# How to speed up NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I'm using CoreData to store a collection of 200k quotes.
I created a Quote CoreData Entity and made the actual text of the quote, be an attribute of this entity (called `text`)

The issue is that my predicate takes a super long time to run. Is there any way to speed this up?:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Quote")

fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "text contains %@", searchWord)
```

This takes about 7 seconds to run.
I would appreciate any suggestions on how to speed it up (even if it involves changing the format that I store the data in)

Thanks so much.